# PWM and PPM using 555 timer

Tags: 555, vco

I get what PWM is and how it can be done using a 555 astable circuit. However I feel I don't completely get what PPM is how its circuit works. I understand the VCO circuit, but I don't see how it can be used as PPM modulator simply by varying UTP and LTP using the pin5. I don't see much difference between PWM and PPM in below circuits. Both seem to produce varying width pulses. Shouldn't the pulse width be fixed in PPM and just the position change ? Could somebody please help me understand how the VCO in second figure acts as a PPM modulator ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like people mean different things by PPM. That's not what I'd call PPM, though an argument could be made that it has elements of PPM about it. It's a modulator that 'does what it does, whatever you call it'.

Comment: Thank you @Neil_UK so this is indeed a weird circuit for PPM. I'll try googling other variations and see if it makes sense.. :)

Comment: The second case is in fact fairly conventional PPM, the polarity of the signal in this particular circuit merely happens to be *inverted* compared to many conceptual presentations, and then a bit oddly labeled.

Answer (score 2):

The negative going pulse is in different positions so it's ppm.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: This is basically correct; but it would be more complete to say that the *width* of the negative going pulse is constant, while its *position* changes.  Part of the issue originates with the odd wording of the diagram in the question; it would be more typical to say that the information is encoded in the pulse *spacing* while the *width* (in this case of the negative portion) is constant.  Maybe it's just that humans are used to looking at active-high pulses, while this circuit happens to produce active-low ones.